# location.hash = "abc.xyz" causes reload?

Tags: html, url, browser-history

I have trouble debugging why this is causing a reload:

```
location.hash = "abc.xyz"
```

There is probably some kind of event handler defined further upstream ...
How can I find out and fix this?

Comment: It doesn't for me.. what browser are you using?

Comment: If you're using an older version of IE (=< 8), then it's a bug which causes `location.hash` to reload

Comment: That bug doesn't happen in IE9 from the console. I'd check to see if you're not inadvertently submitting a form. For example, if you are using `<input type="button"/>` in IE to set the hash, or in any browser using a link to do it, this will surely reload the page

Comment: I am using Chrome ... Let me know if you have any ideas regarding neutralizing the event handler ...